# export Pandas dataframe to txt according field location

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that I want to export to a text file where the field are located by their position/indexes (not like a `csv` with separators).
I could create a function that does that, but it will most likely be slow and I'm hoping that Pandas would integrate a such feature.

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,300], 'b':[10,200,30], 'c':[100, 2, 3]})
export(df, index_position={'a':0, 'b':5, 'c':9}, 'sometxtfile.txt')
```

The output I'm expecting (I don't want the header)

```
0123456789012 ## index position as a reference
a    b   c    ## Where the variable must be
------------- ## The file starts after that
1    10  100  ## a is starting at index 0
20   200 2    ## b is starting at index 5
300  30  3    ## c is starting at index 9
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What should be logic behind delimeters?

Comment: @Slam, I don't get your question. The delimiter would be with a variable length (depending on values around)

Comment: I don't think I understand the functionality behind `pos_index={'a':0, 'b':5}`. Your output looks like mapping those elements from `a` and `b` that have the same index to the same line (eg. `a[0] b[0]` in the first line). Could you explain a bit further please?

Comment: Agree with @KacperFloriański. In your output, you say `2 is placed at index 5`, but depending on the direction of indexing, I only see the possible indices as `[3]`, `[4]`, or `[1][1]`. Additionally, your last input for `B` is `20`, but your output shows `30`. Is that a typo or part of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I updated / corrected the example, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works, but it's not really elegant. Comments are welcome, feel free to criticize.

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,300], 'b':[10,200,30], 'c':[100, 2, 3]})
positions = {0:'a', 5:'b', 9:'c'}
```

String creation:

```
def exporttxt(df, positions):
  indexes = [x for x in positions.keys()]
  indexes.sort()
  df = df[[positions[x] for x in indexes]]
  toreturn = ''
  for _, line in df.iterrows():
    newline = ['{}'.format(line[positions[i]]).ljust(l) for i, l in zip(indexes, lengths)]
    toreturn = toreturn + '\n' + ''.join(newline)
  return toreturn

print(exporttxt(df, positions))
```

Output:

```
1    10  100
20   200 2
300  30  3
```